# what is environment variable configuration in ssis and what registry entry configuration in ssis

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, msbi

I am learning SSIS. Now I'm stuck with configurations. I have done xml, parent package and SQL configuration but I am not understanding what is Environment Variable configuration and what is registry entry configuration in SSIS.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Environment Variable** configuration means that you want to configure your variable(s) in the SSIS Package to take the value from an **Environment Variable**. Environment Variables are set at the Computer / Server / System level.

For example, you could store the connection string for a database in an environment variable and configure all your package that run on that server, and use that database, to take the connection string value from that variable.

[image]

Same with Registry Configuration setting, where you have Registry keys that contain your SSIS variable values.

See the following MSDN Article for detailed explanation on all the configuration types.

#### [Defining a Configuration Approach for Integration Services Packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671625.aspx)

I know SSIS tends to be a little confusing when you get started :) I went through the same issues.

Comment: how is the  career of MSBI compare to sap

Comment: according to me sap is having more market than msbi but in india, United states, Europe, Uk MSBI JOBS are more.

Comment: Shiva can you tell me MSBI Career over Sap

Comment: Depends on where you are looking and how much experienced you are. See https://www.dice.com and search for SAP jobs, SSIS / BI jobs, and you'll get an idea.