# SSIS packages loose project level connections when deploying to SSIS server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to deploy around 20 SSIS packages which use SSIS project level connections to my SSIS server. The problem is that when I import them to the SSIS server they loose their connection.

It only works when i convert the project level connections to package level connections, but I want to avoid this since this would be inconvenient because all packages use the same connection.

Does someone know a fix for this?

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888087/what-is-environment-variable-configuration-in-ssis-and-what-registry-entry-confi) on using "environment variables" with your SSIS project.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issues with the help of this thread: 
[SSIS Connection not found in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874722/ssis-connection-not-found-in-package)

One of the guys gave the hint that you can also deploy a whole SSIS project to SQL Server using the Integration Services Catalog.

In this Microsoft Documentation, everything is explained very well:

- [Deploy Integration Services (SSIS) Projects and Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017)

Might seem odd that I didn't lookup the doc before I asked the question here in Stackoverflow, but I just couldn't imagine that it is not possible to deploy a single SSIS package when using Project Level connections. A really dumb decision from Microsoft to be honest^^